# SQLite 3 Max() function

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to caculate the age of the oldest person and display only that peson from a group.

this code below gives me the right person but the incorrect age (Margret, 69)

```
SELECT FirstName as Name,
max((strftime('%Y', 'now') - strftime('%Y', BirthDate))
     - (strftime('%m-%d', 'now') < strftime('%m-%d', BirthDate) )) as Age
FROM Employee;
```

this code below gives me all the people and the correct ages (Margret, 58)

```
SELECT FirstName as Name,
  (strftime('%Y', 'now') - strftime('%Y', BirthDate))
     - (strftime('%m-%d', 'now') < strftime('%m-%d', BirthDate) ) as Age
FROM Employee;
```

Could someone help explain please?

Comment: Which SQLite version?

Answer (score 0):

It probably depends on how your `BirthDate` in defined but if it is sqlite3 standard yyyy-mm-dd try:

```
SELECT FirstName as Name, CAST( (julianday('now') - julianday(BirthDate)) / 365 AS INTEGER) as age  
    FROM Employee;
```

and

```
SELECT FirstName as Name, max(CAST( (julianday('now') - julianday(BirthDate)) / 365 AS INTEGER)) as age  
    FROM Employee;
```